# Adding muliple rows to a TableLayout

Tags: java, android

When adding just the first row everything go well, but after I've added the second row, it fails.

```
pupils=db.getAllPupilsPupil();
events=db.getAllEvents();
TableLayout tableLayout =(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
bubbleSort(events);
TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
row.setLayoutParams(lp);
TextView tv;
tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("events ");
row.addView(tv);
for(int i=0;i<pupils.size();i++) {
    tv = new TextView(this);
    String name=pupils.get(i).getName()+" ";
    tv.setText(name);
    tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));
    row.addView(tv);
}
tableLayout.addView(row,0);
tableLayout.addView(row,1);
```

**the logcat**

Process: com.hazofim.thescouts, PID: 17992 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hazofim.thescouts/com.hazofim.thescouts.attendes}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4915) at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4746) at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:427) at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4686) at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:409) at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4659) at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:400) at com.hazofim.thescouts.attendes.onCreate(attendes.java:48) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: tow last sentence
tableLayout.addView(row,0);
tableLayout.addView(row,1);
when i added the second row the app fail and with just the first row averything go well

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent that error message:

> The specified child already has a parent.

There need to be two instances of `TableRow` (the "specified child"), no matter their duplicate content:

```
for(int i=0; i < pupils.size(); i++) {

    TableRow row1 = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow row2 = new TableRow(this);
    TextView tv   = new TextView(this);

    tv.setText(pupils.get(i).getName());
    tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));

    row1.addView(tv);
    row2.addView(tv);

    tableLayout.addView(row1);
    tableLayout.addView(row2);
}
```

method [.addView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout#addView(android.view.View)) doesn't even need an `index` passed (it adds items to the end, by default).

Comment: my problem is when i add the second row the app fall

Comment: @אילייקורן-יב7 you are not adding any second row, but the same row (which refers to the same object) twice... if you'd add a stack-trace of the crash, I could possible tell more about it.

Comment: i need to add the same row twice

Comment: @אילייקורן-יב7 would need to see the stack-trace to tell why it is happening. you could try with two separate instances of `TableRow`, so that there would be two different references passed.

Comment: what is stack-trace?
and its fall for any row that i add

Comment: you can find the [stack-trace](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces) in the `logcat` window, when producing that crash. this would tell what the actual problem is.

Comment: "The specified child already has a parent." confirms what I've wrote...  try with two separate instances of `TableRow`, so that each of them can get it's parent set once and once only.

Comment: and if i want to add this row like dynamic times(like in for loop)

Comment: @אילייקורן-יב7 just move the `addView()` calls inside the loop. when not passing an `index` argument , it will automatically have the correct index. `new TableRow` needs to be called inside the loop.